# Angular 8.0 Data share among component and service

Tags: angular

I am working to automate a manual form. I am new to angular.

I have a stepper control in app.component with 5 steps. I have created 5 component and placed one inside each stepper.

```
<mat-step label="Start">
    <app-project-location></app-project-location>            
</mat-step>    
<mat-step [stepControl]="licensedContractorFormGroup" label="Property Owner Information">
    <app-property-owner></app-property-owner>      
</mat-step>
<mat-step [stepControl]="licensedContractorFormGroup" label="Project In Charge">
    <app-project-in-change-details></app-project-in-change-details>
</mat-step>
```

Each inner component above has buttons to navigate to `previous` and `next`.

When I fill the `<app-project-location>` form and submit next, this form takes the form input, calls the service which call the API, and returns the data fill in the next component table.

**Question:**

How can I pass the form data from this component to another component which has no parent child relationship?

I have called the service and it returns a JSON object, How can I make it return as observables?

Comment: https://robferguson.org/blog/2017/08/31/angular-4-and-sibling-component-interaction/  Check out `Angular Sibling Component Communication`. I would use `Ngrx`/redux for this though because it can get complicated if you keep re-using this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if a very good choice to use a component for each step.

Then, as @AliF50 told you, you should check this [link](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

So, to keep it short:

1) Put all the global variables you want to share between your 5 components in the `.component.ts` of the component containing the stepper.

2) Use the `Output` events in the childs (the 5 components) to notify and send data to the parent (the component containing the stepper).

3) The parent, depending on the received event (from step 1, step 2, etc..), will then set the variables of each childs using the `Input` properties.

Answer (score 0):

you can use observable like this :

**Service**

```
private message: Subject<Your_Data_Type>;

constructor() {
    this.message = new Subject<Your_Data_Type>();

    // set new value for variable and emit that
    this.message.next(new_value);
  }

public getMessage(): Observable<Your_Data_Type> {
    return this.message.asObservable();
  }
```

**Component**

and in your component subscribe your function :

```
this.yourService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
  this.data = message;
});
```